# In react native how to add selected user image with image picker and assign the image to current signed in user using the firestore database version9?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Image Picker to add the selected image, but not sure how to assign the current image to the user in firestore database.

```
const UserImage = (currentUser) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const addImage = async () => {
    let _image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    const mountainImagesRef = ref(storage, `Users/${currentUser.uid}`);
    console.log(mountainImagesRef);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(_image));
    if (!_image.cancelled) {
      setImage(_image.uri);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle this.

One of them is that save the firestore storage url as a field into the User data.

When you fetch the user data, you can use the firestore storage url to use/show the photo.

When you upload the photo to firestore storage, it will return the uploaded file's url. You will just store the url into the User data so simply you just match the photo to the User.